# How can I use values from the [Setup] section in code?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I use values from the [Setup] section in code?

I suspect I'm using the tool incorrectly; maybe I should be doing this in a different way entirely.

```
[Setup]
MyValue=some value

[code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // blank
  MsgBox(GetEnv('MyValue'), mbError, MB_OK);

  // no expansion occurs
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant('MyValue'), mbError, MB_OK);

  // unknown constant "MyValue".
  MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{MyValue}'), mbError, MB_OK);

  Result := true;
end;
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the aim of that declaration ? Do you want to have a variable which will be visible in scope of the script section as well as in code ? Or, are you just looking for a way to declare a variable for code section ?

Comment: You can use [Proprocessor `defines`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define)

Comment: i'd like to be able to use values from the [Setup] section in code.  is the answer maybe to push the things i need to access into preprocessor defines?

Comment: Literally to the question *"How to use values from [Setup] section in code ?"* would be the answer like use e.g. `{#SetupSetting('AppName')}`. But I guess it's not that you want because you cannot declare your own "variable" there (which seems you're trying). Your last comment still didn't answer my initial question. Are you looking for a way how to declare variables visible in a scope of the whole script (visible in sections like `[Setup]` as well as in `[Code]` one) ? Or, will you work with that variable just in `[Code]` section ?

Comment: I thought I could define my own values there.  I was hoping to define values there that would be used while copying files as well as used in the Code section.  The DRY principle is what I'm wishing to follow.  I think for any values that i feel the desire to do this should be declared as #define values and they can be used to pass values to [Setup] as well as code.  That will work.  you could put it in as an answer and i will mark it as correct.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot declare variable in the [`[Setup]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupsection.htm) section. This section may contain only a set of predefined directives. If your aim was to define a constant which could be used in script section entries as well as in script coding [`[Code]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcreating.htm) section, then you were looking for preprocessor variables declared by [`#define`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) directive. For example:

```
#define MyValue "some value"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyValue}
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[INI]
Filename: "MyProg.ini"; Section: "InstallSettings"; Key: "InstallPath"; String: "{#MyValue}"

[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  MsgBox('{#MyValue}', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

What actually happens behind a `{#MyValue}` statement is that the preprocessor [`emits`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) the value of the defined `MyValue` constant to the final script.

Comment: You may also read a value from the `[Setup]` section directly, removing the need for `#define`, like this: `ExpandConstant('{#SetupSetting("AppName")}')`